# XUnit test to return a see if a list is being returned

Tags: c#, tdd, xunit

I'm learning Unit Testing and I'm struggling to grasp how we can test to see if a type of list is returning, not necessarily the content of the list but to make sure its a LIST that is being returned.

Returning an empty list of strings

```
    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        var names = new List<string>();

        return names;
    }
```

My test, trying to return a typeofList:

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetListTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(typeof(List<string>), GetList());
    }
```

Comment: `GetList().GetType()`...

Comment: ...well don't I feel stupid. Thanks Johnny I think its time i go to bed :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
Assert.Equal(typeof(List<string>), GetList());
```

you are testing whether the type of string list is equal with the actual list. You are comparing apples with oranges. You can do this:

```
Assert.Equal(typeof(List<string>), GetList().GetType());
```

Also, you can construct composite logical criteria and assert equal to those, so you can check whether the type is the expected one and empty in the same test.

Answer (score 2):

I belive this package can help you:

https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly

Assertion can be tricky sometimes to understand what is going on. `Shouldly` make asserts easier.

With `Shouldly` you can make checking types like this:

```
yourList.ShouldBeOfType<List<string>>();
```

if type of `yourList` matched `List<string>` it will return `true`. If not, `false`. You can install `Shouldly` from nuget as well.

With this package you can refactor `Assert.Equal` to something like:

```
yourObject.yourProperty.ShouldBe("Some Stirng To Compare 'yourProperty;");
```

and example with int:

```
yourInteger.ShouldBe(10);
```

Comment: Basicly its not an answer to your question but please consider upvote this answer :)

Comment: upvoted as its extremely helpful and no doubt i shall use this in future. many thanks!

Comment: @michasaucer you are right, this is not an actual answer, but deserves the upvote nevertheless.